# adb error: protocol fault (status 48 54 54 50?!)

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-tools

adb stopped working in both Android Studio and command line suddenly.
I'm using powershell in Windows:

```
..sdk\platform-tools> .\adb.exe devices
List of devices attached
error: protocol fault (status 48 54 54 50?!)
```

I can't find that these status code mean anywhere, any help will be appreciated.

I'm using adb version 1.0.36

```
..sdk\platform-tools> .\adb.exe version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision fd9e4d07b0f5-android
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `status XX XX XX XX` part of the `adb`'s `protocol fault` error message is not really a "status". It is just a hex encoded content of the first 4 bytes of the response that `adb` got back when it tried to connect to a port (which it most likely assumed belonged to an emulator instance). Your reads `'HTTP'` which suggests that you have a web server running on a non-standard (for a web server) port.

Use `netstat -b` command to find what it is and kill it.

Comment: Just wondering how do you know about this? Also can you mention the port we are looking for is 5037. It took me sometime to find out that is the port adb is using.

Comment: Android is an open source project so anyone who's truly interested can get a look